# Is it good practice to highlight proper nouns in code tags?

Tags: discussion, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a functional purpose to putting things in code text here?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/is-there-a-functional-purpose-to-putting-things-in-code-text-here)

SteveC is editing a lot of other users' questions and answers to put the names of books, place names and races in backticks, which `highlights them like this`.

Is this a good idea? Should we ask him to stop?

Comment: Check out my question, linked above.

Comment: Thanks. I've answered there and voted to close my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a big user here, but here's my two cents:

I could see highlighting certain specific game terms, *when they are a big deal to the overall context of the post*. Like, I dunno, highlighting class abilities for D&D 3/4 does make the text a bit more readable in some ways. It sorta stops you a little and says, "Here, here is the thing you should look up." Actual links to some kind of reference thingy would be preferable, though.

It seems absolutely pointless to highlight [fictional place names](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12227/possible-explanations-for-the-mourning).

Coming here without any foreknowledge of the site's style, seeing `lots` and `lots` of highlight text in one paragraph was `really jarring` and didn't really make `the text` easier to read.

Comment: +1 completely agree